# A question from Leon Simon's "Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory"

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, grassmannians

In a book I am reading (Leon Simon, Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory) at some point the author claims that if a certain property $(P)$ holds for almost every $n$-plane $\pi\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ in the grassmannian $G(n+k,n)$ (which is a smooth manifold, hence the notion of null set is well-defined), then there exist "many" orthonormal frames, i.e. $N$-ples of $n$-planes $(\pi_1,...,\pi_N)$ where the $n$-plane $\pi_i$ is orthogonal to the $n$-plane $\pi_j$ for all $i,j=1,...,N=$${n+k}\choose{n}$, $i\neq j$, such that $(P)$ holds for each $\pi_i$, for $i=1,...,N$.

While this result makes a lot of sense intuitively, I am not able to prove it formally. In facts, I cannot even prove that there is one $N$-ple that works.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: (P) is a property of n-planes or a property of vectors or what else? And what are the $\pi_i$ ? Thx

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes they are n-planes. I have edited the question to make it more explicit. The idea is that the $\pi_i$ are the coordinated $n$-planes of some orthogonal change of coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.

Comment: @PietroMajer Given a set $A$, property (P) is the statement "$\mathcal{H}^{n}(p_\pi(A))=0$", where $p_\pi$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\pi$. In the case when $A$ is purely unrectifiable, the property is true for $a.e.$ $\pi$ because of the Besicovitch-Federer structure theorem. I am then asking how to get that it is true for all coordinated planes, where the coordinates are with respect to some orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.